# Software for live updating webpage

Tags: node.js

So a quick rundown, I need to figure out a way for a CSV that is on the webserver to be parsed and then automatically displayed on the frontend. And every time a new .csv file is put in the directory, it's displayed on the frontend.

I've recently started working with Node.js so I am wondering if this is what I should use but I'm not sure how.

Can anyone please give me some guidance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) to implement node.js and csv parsing.

As for the csv file, why not simply maintain the same name for the csv file for each upload?  Every time it is uploaded, overwrite the existing file and your node.js parser will always call the latest file and display the latest information.

If you are adding a csv file and wish to also keep the previous files, as in a list where the user can select the file they want, you'll store the parsed data in a database for each file.  A file handler will decide when a new file has been added, parse it and load into database.  In this scenario, the web page is created from database.